# Store query result into php array to echo result as per index

Tags: php, mysql

I have below code which queries result from 2 Mysql columns. I want to store them in a single array. I went thru many questions and answers and tried a lot and managed below code:

```
$query10 = $conn->query("SELECT CONCAT(step1, ' ', step2) AS A1 FROM workflow1 where nx_version='NX11IP33'");
$array10 = Array();
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $query10)){
    $new_array[] = $row; // Inside while loop
}
print_r($new_array);
```

**Current output:**

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [A1] => 10 2 ) )
```

**Desired output:**

```
Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 2 )
```

Any help.

Comment: You specifically `CONCAT()` both columns to a single in your sql query. And then you ask why they are concatenated instead of being separate? Well...

Comment: I see, I am new to php. How can I modify query then...?

Comment: I posted some answer below. You did not say anything about your data scheme, so I kept that a bit abstract. Hope it helps, have fun!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specifically `CONCAT()` both columns to a single in your sql query. And then you ask why they are concatenated instead of being separate?

The answer then obviously is to fetch both columns separately:

```
<?php
//...
$query = $conn->query("SELECT step1, step2 FROM workflow1 WHERE nx_version='NX11IP33'");
if ($query) {
    $result = [];
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $result[] = $row;
    }
    print_r($result);
}
```

The output of that will be something like this:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [step1] => 10
        [step2] => 2 
    ) 
)
```

---

If `nx_version` is a unique key, so if it is guaranteed that you will receive only a single row in the query result, then you can simplify that:

```
<?php
//...
$query = $conn->query("SELECT step1, step2 FROM workflow1 WHERE nx_version='NX11IP33' LIMIT 1");
if ($query) {
    $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    print_r($result);
}
```

The output of that will be something like this:

```
Array ( 
    [step1] => 10
    [step2] => 2 
)
```

---

Finally, if you prefer numeric indexes instead of associative ones (as your desired result in the question suggests), then use `mysqli_fetch_row()` instead of `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`.

Comment: Yes, nx_version is a unique key. I was in need of second code you posted as I will be printing 2 values using index in 2 html table cells. Thank you!

Comment: @SamadhanGaikwad You are welcome! Good luck with your project!